# Firebase does not work with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Following Firebase's tutorial, I was able to start posting data immediately from the frontend, using the cdn:

`<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>`

and:

```
      var myDataRef = new firebase('https://intense-torch-1234.firebaseio.com/');

      $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          var name = $('#nameInput').val();
          var text = $('#messageInput').val();
          myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
          $('#messageInput').val('');
        }
      });

      myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        console.log('TESTING', snapshot);
      });
```

This shows up at my Firebase app location.

I need to use this for NodeJS, so I installed the [NPM Firebase module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase).

I am doing pretty much the same thing here...

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var myDataRef = new firebase('https://intense-torch-1234.firebaseio.com/');

    myDataRef.push({name: 'myname', text: 'sometext'});

    myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        console.log('TESTING', snapshot.val());
    });
```

The console log fires after my request comes in (from Slack) and shows that the data is coming in. However, it is not updating in my Firebase database.

Are there other configurations I need to do for Node NPM firebase?

Comment: What error is returned if you [add a callback to your push method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html)? What's in the JS console? How is exports.handler() invoked?

Comment: Add a completion handler to the `push()` call, which will tell you why the write operation failed: `myDataRef.push({name: 'myname', text: 'sometext'}, function(error) { console.log(error); });`

Answer (score 2):

As for other configurations, you need to import the package by using `require` as per the instructions.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myprojectname.firebaseIO.com/');
myRootRef.set("hello world!");
```

There also should be error messages from node for not doing this.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I didn't include that in the snippet